# Order of siblings and their kids in string

Tags: r, string

I represent a tree in a bracket format in which every level is separated from its upper level by {. The tree is binary (it can have one or 2 kids).
I would like to order the same level siblings in alphabetic order while keeping their kids and sub kids. It means, just to order each 2 kids of the same level by their alphabetic order. 
I have a string str1 which contains the input tree and I would like to get the ordered in string str2.

Here is an example:

```
str1<-"{A{C{D{E}}}{B{F{G{H{I}}}}}}"
```

At the first phase of the order process I would like that str2 be as followed:

```
{A{B{F{G{H{I}}}}}{C{D{E}}}}
```

Just switch between C and all of its kids to and B and all of its sub kids and then going on...
(Since C and B are both second level to their father A. Only one '{' separates between B and C to A)
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) package? You'd just have to write a function to convert your format into and out of a `data.tree`, and then you can use it's `sort` function to alphabetize.

Comment: Thanks Josh. It is not as that simple. The first step is replacing positions between 2 parts: {C{D{E}}} and {B{F{G{H{I}}}}} so after the first step the string will be: {A{B{F{G{H{I}}}}}{C{D{E}}}}. It is not to just order the letters.I think recursion will be best for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think John's comment is likely on the right track--the best way to do what you want, is to take your string and convert it into a proper object-oriented tree structure.  Subsequently, you can manipulate you data as a tree instead of as a string, and once you're done doing stuff you can revert the tree structure back into your string format if desired.  `data.tree` us an ideal package for this, because it already has powerful tree-manipulation tools (including a sort function) built-in, so no re-inventing the wheel.

Fortunately, such conversion is relatively easy with recursion.  Here is code to convert a string to a `data.tree`:

```
library(data.tree)

peek.next.node <- function(x){  #Helper function reads the next node (as a string) out of the char vector x
  return(paste(x[2:(which(x=="{"|x=="}")[2]-1)],collapse=""))
}

remove.next.node <- function(x){ #Helper function removes node at the start of the char vector x
  return(x[(which(x=="{"|x=="}")[2]):length(x)])
}

recurse.from.char.vector <- function (x,n){ #inspect input char vector, adding nodes to n if x starts with '{' and returning if x starts with '}'.  Will loop until return
  i<-1
  while(x[1]=="{"){
    new.node.name <- paste(c(peek.next.node(x),"_",i),collapse="")
    child.n <- n$AddChild(new.node.name,label=peek.next.node(x))
    i <- i+1
    x <- remove.next.node(x)
    x <- recurse.from.char.vector(x,child.n)
  }
  return (x[2:length(x)])
}

string.to.tree <- function(x){ #returns head node for a finished tree by calling a recursive parse function
  x.vec <- strsplit(x,"")[[1]]
  head <- Node$new(peek.next.node(x.vec),label = peek.next.node(x.vec))
  recurse.from.char.vector(remove.next.node(x.vec),head) 
  return(head)
}
```

Note that this code will work even if your node labels are more than one character, and it will also work for non-binary trees.

Going back to a string from a tree is even easier, since the `data.tree` objects more naturally lend themselves to recursion:

```
recurse.to.char.vector <- function(n){
  return.vec <-unlist(c("{",n$label))
  if(length(n$children)>0)return.vec <- unlist(c(return.vec,sapply(n$children,recurse.to.char.vector)))
  return.vec <- unlist(c(return.vec,"}"))
  return(return.vec)
}

tree.to.string <- function(n){
  char.vector <- recurse.to.char.vector(n)
  return (paste(char.vector,collapse=""))
}
```

And here is your example: converted, sorted, and converted back:

```
> str1<-"{A{C{D{E}}}{B{F{G{H{I}}}}}}"
> test.tree <- string.to.tree(str1)
> str1
[1] "{A{C{D{E}}}{B{F{G{H{I}}}}}}"
> test.tree$Sort("label")
> tree.to.string(test.tree)
[1] "{A{B{F{G{H{I}}}}}{C{D{E}}}}"
```

Note that you want to do the `Sort` and `tee.to.string` on separate lines--on some edge cases (like a single-node "tree") `Sort()` will return a `NULL` value

In the comments, you asked about "seeing" the tree without the child ID numbers.  That can be accomplished by setting a formatting function on the `levelName` attribute for the tree.  Basically, whenever you `print` a tree, the tree cycles through every node and prints the `levelName` attribute--and you can format it like any other printed attribute.

An example format function:

```
strip.num.from.levelName <- function(x){ #If string ends with _something, strip out everything after the last underscore
  x.vec <- strsplit(x,"")[[1]]
  which.sep <- which(x.vec == "_")
  if(length(which.sep)<=0)
    return(x)
  else 
    return(paste(x.vec[1:(tail(which.sep,1)-1)],collapse=""))
}
```

After making this function, apply it to the tree with `SetFormat(test.tree,"levelName",strip.num.from.levelName)`.  That will remove the number from all the simple printout of the tree

Comment: I wondered if there is a way to solve this problem without transformation into trees format. Only with string manipulation? And if there is a way to sort trees (such as J48) directly using this code.

Comment: Dear Frank, Please refer to the following example: str1<-"{ASTV{DP{DP{ALTV}}}{DP{ALTV{DL}{LBE{e}}}}}". In this case I get a wrong test.tree can you explain why?

Comment: @Avi From a logical standpoint, you are going to be doing tree manipulation even if all you use are `string` functions, except this way the code is easier to read, easier to modify, and easier to fix if something goes wrong.  For example, the error you encounter with your new example is because (I just discovered)  `data.tree` doesn't like having multiple child nodes with non-unique names.  I fixed this by appending a id number to all the node names in the tree and moving the raw node name into an attribute--only 3 extra lines of code, thanks to all the handy functionality in `data.tree`

Comment: @Avi Also, is the new example string not already sorted?  the only nodes with children are ASTV (both children are DP, and thus no sort needed) and ALTV (children DL and LBE are already alphabetized)

Comment: Dear Frank, Thanks a lot. If the tree is sorted I would it to stay as is with no changes. Does the code support it? 
Yes - the example is already sorted.
Is there a way to see the test.tree without numbers? Thanks a lot for your wonderful solution.

Comment: @Avi Depends on what you mean by "see."  There's an attribute on each node called `levelName`, which is basically the string that prints for that node whenever you call `print(test.tree)`.  You can use the `SetFormat` method to format that string however you want, including removing the trailing numeral.  I'll add some code to my answer to do so.

Comment: Frank, Can you please find out why if str1<-"{A}" I get the value of tree.to.string {} (empty)?

Comment: @Avi Both of the above inputs work as I would expect them to.  `"{A}"` goes in and comes back out as `"{A}"`, and your second string is a sorted version of the first string.  Since we are getting kinda nitty-gritty in the details, I have created a chat room to discuss in further detail: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90904/room-for-avi-and-frank